# Set a watcher on specific file/directory in git

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to be notified if someone changes a file/directory in our git repository (for example tsconfig.json).
We are using local gitlab (not sure if it's EE).

Few ways this could work:

- override git pull/fetch locally and show files changed if any
- implement web hook in gitlab to send email (immediately/daily/weekly...)
- native support on specific platforms
- ...

Also does this exist on github/bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a remote hook in your central repository, which will send you a mail if the important files are changed. How to do that should be pretty self explanatory from the samples coming with git, and from the git book.